# Are suffixes in Ido agglutinative?

Tags: morphology, typology, ido

I was thinking what is the correct way to say "Little princess" in Ido.

(EN) Little princess - Little (indicates the "size") Princess (descendant of some royal crown and that descendant is female).

(ES) Princesita - Princes (root), -it- (suffix for "litte"), -a (indicates female gender).

We should translate as in english like "Mikra princino"? or in the Spanish way like "Princetino"?

If Ido suffixes are agglutinative, is there a particular order? "-et" suffix for little "-in" for female... we could get "Princineto".

Comment: Longer strings of suffixes are very ordinary in Esperanto, so I would assume they're acceptable in Ido.

Answer (score 1):

After a research, I finally found this example which explains this.

> si quieres decir una perra (adulta) pequeña, el orden adecuado es entonces perra+pequeña = hundineto. El orden contrario es poco natural y hace dudar al que oye la palabra *hundetino = perrito hembra*

So the valid ones for Little princess are:
1. Mikra princino = "Little" + "female descendant of some royal crown"
2. Princineto = A female descendant of some royal crown who is little.

"Princetino" would be like:
A little descendant of some royal crown who is female.